# Hyper-V Gaming - Mouse Issue

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

I'm VERY new to all this, but was able to follow a youtube tutorial to set up a VM using Hyper-V to play two accounts on the same game simultaneously.  I'm using Win10 on the VM, Win11 on the host.

I'm having an issue with the mouse in the VM... The mouse doesn't 'lock' into the VM.  When I'm playing the game, I'll try to turn the camera to look around, and the mouse will just move right out of the VM onto my host machine main monitor.

I don't see any settings that jump out at me in the Hyper-V Manager, and google has so far not been helpful.  How can I keep my mouse locked into the VM?

Comment: Just curious what the game is and whether this really the only option. I can't imagine the performance to be very good, and if it is an MMO, some of them actually supports multi-client.

Comment: The game is "Beasts of Bermuda".  The performance is just fine for my purposes, and I had no issues running through sandboxie, until the last update necessitated I change to HyperV.

Answer (score 0):

Games often run a structure known as 'mouse warp' which keeps the cursor focussed within the game - otherwise your avatar would stop turning when the cursor hits the screen edge, etc.
It may be that your VM overrides this behaviour with its own, if the VM's game screen is not running in fullscreen.

Two possible solutions could be

1. run it in fullscreen, or
2. remove the 'additions' that the VM uses in order to allow the cursor to pass out of the VM [this will usually necessitate some key-combo to release the cursor back to your host OS instead].

[I've known some games with a deeply-buried pref to disable mouse warp, but I don't think that would help in this instance.]

Comment: I am running in fullscreen, and I've already got HyperV configured to only release mouse when I press ctrl+alt+left arrow.  I'm wondering if this has something to do with the 'enhanced session', which I'm unable to activate since my VM is running win10 home.

Answer (score 0):

VMWare has a feature to lock the Mouse within the VM.
Hyper-V does not, as far as i know.